# Statistical Modeling with the combination of two models

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

I'm having a modeling problem now. Assume we have discrete random variable Y and continuous random variables X and Z. First, we assume a logistic regression between Y and Z.(Assumption One) Also, we assume a regression model X~Y+Z. (Y is used as a categorical variable.)(Assumption Two)

If we want to estimate the parameters from the two models at the same time, which kind of likelihood function should we assume? BTW, is this way of modeling reasonable? It looks weird to me. But I couldn't tell which part is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look up [Directed Acyclic Graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Essentially what I think you're saying is that there is an arrow from Z to Y, from Z to X and from Y to X. General inference methods are available in Bayesian stats for this type of problem (e.g. BUGS, STAN).

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at the BUGS. It seems that MCMC only handle this kind of relationship among the parameters. But here X,Y,Z are variables. Does it still fit?

Comment: It makes a difference which are observed and which are unobserved among X,Y,Z in terms of designing an inference procedure.